# QuickFix do not validate user defined fields for specific message only

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I implement QuickFix client and I parse SecurityDefinition message ('d') with many user-defined fields. The service provider wants me not to validate user-defined fields, as he says that they add new fields from time to time and don't want to make us (clients) dependant of this.

Is there a way to cancel validation of user-defined fields for one specific message only?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Configuring QuickFIX](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html) page, in particular the ValidateUserDefinedFields parameter:

> **ValidateUserDefinedFields**: If set to N, user defined fields will not be rejected if they are not defined in the data dictionary, or are present in messages they do not belong to.

This does not turn off validation of one particular message of course. It turns off validation for User Defined Fields in messages where they are not defined in the Data Dictionary. If the `SecurityDefinition` message is the only one they add fields to without prior notification then setting `ValidateUserDefinedFields` to N is probably good enough for you because:

1. In other messages, either you defined User Defined Fields in your Data Dictionary and they are validated, or you haven't and they are not validated. In the latter case because you probably won't use those fields there's no harm.
2. In `SecurityDefinition` only the User Defined Fields you put in your Data Dictionary are validated, other UDF's aren't which is what you want.

If there's still a use-case that would prohibit you from using that configuration option, please let me know in the comments section.